# packages declared inside system verilog interface

Tags: interface, package, system-verilog

Is it possible to define a package inside of a SystemVerilog Interface?

example:

```
interface my_ifc();

    package a;
        logic reset;
        logic clk_usb;

    endpackage

    logic Rwn; 
    logic [7:0] Addr;


endinterface
```

Comment: what would be a point of it? From this example it looks like you just need a struct.

Answer (score 1):

No. A package must be declared outside of any other nested scope (at the compilation unit level)

Answer (score 0):

Package is a way to share code between modules, interfaces and programs in SystemVerilog. In your case, you could create a package outside the interface and then just import whatever you wish inside the package, in order to be made visible. Like this:

```
import a::*;
```

But the package, written inside the interface, is of no usefulness.